# ¿Cómo escribir una regex en varias líneas?

Tags: angular, typescript, regex

Tengo una regex escrita de la siguiente forma:

```
export const nameRegex = /^(?=.{2,40}$)(?:[a-zA-zÀ-ÿ']+(?:[\s][a-zA-zÀ-ÿ'])*)+$/;
```

Pero quisiera escribir las diferentes partes de la regex línea por línea, para hacerlo más legible, algo como esto.

```
/^(?=.{2,40}$)
(?:[a-zA-zÀ-ÿ']+(?:[\s][a-zA-zÀ-ÿ'])*)+$/;
```

Sin embargo marca error ya que no es válido escribirla en varías líneas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr de otra forma, utilizando template strings (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings).

```
export const nameRegex = new RegExp(`^(?=.{2,40}$)
    (?:[a-zA-zÀ-ÿ']+(?:[\s][a-zA-zÀ-ÿ'])*)+$`);
```

RegExp acepta un segundo parámetro para los flags.

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp